# I have this impersonat script written in VBS, it currenly asks for a computer name, how do I make it pull the computer name from a txt list?

Tags: vbscript

I have this impersonate script written in VBS. It currently asks for a computer name. How do I make it pull the computer name from a text list? Instead of asking for a computer name I want it to automatically read each computer name from a text file.

I have tried this but it fails no matter how I write it.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const TriStateUseDefault = -2
strList = "computers.txt"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objList = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strList, ForReading, False, TriStateUseDefault)
arrComputers = Split(objList.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
objList.Close

For Each strComputer In arrComputers
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set objProcess = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Process")

    strCommand = "sc config lanmanserver start= demand"
    strCommand2 = "Net start lanmanserver"

    errReturn = objProcess.Create(strCommand, null, null, intProcessID)

    If errReturn = 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "Lanmanserver was changed to manual: " & intProcessID
    Else
        WScript.Echo "WinRM could not be started due to error: " & errReturn
    End If

    WScript.Sleep 5000 '5 seconds

    errReturn = objProcess.Create(strCommand2, Null, Null, intProcessID)

    If errReturn = 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "The Server Service was started with a process ID: " & intProcessID
    Else
        WScript.Echo "The Server Service could not be started due to error: " & errReturn
```

This is the original code:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objcomputer = InputBox("Please Enter a Computer Name to Start the Server Service on.")

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & objComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objProcess = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Process")

strCommand = "sc config lanmanserver start= demand"
strCommand2 = "Net start lanmanserver"

errReturn = objProcess.Create(strCommand, Null, Null, intProcessID)

If errReturn = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Lanmanserver was changed to manual: " & intProcessID
Else
    WScript.Echo "WinRM could not be started due to error: " & errReturn
End If

WScript.Sleep 5000 '5 seconds

errReturn = objProcess.Create(strCommand2, null, null, intProcessID)

If errReturn = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "The Server Service was started with a process ID: " & intProcessID
Else
    WScript.Echo "The Server Service could not be started due to error: " & errReturn
End If
```

I need it to be able to insert the computer name in by text file and repeat for each computer name.

Comment: Justin. "It fails" is not a useful error description. Describe exactly what is going wrong and where it does, and what you expected it to do.

Comment: What Geert said. Also, your first code snippet is incomplete (missing a closing `End If` and `Next`).

Comment: yeah, ansgar it would seem that so far if i add an, "end, if or Next" statement it errors everytime with a "expected statement" error. but i wasnt sure if it needed to end with an )

Comment: what i would like it to do is pull the  pc name from a txt file instead of entering it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like Ansgar was right I dunno what I was thinking!!! I tried the below code and it worked. thanks!

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const TriStateUseDefault = -2
strList = "computers.txt"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objList = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strList, ForReading, False, TriStateUseDefault)
arrComputers = Split(objList.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
objList.Close

For Each strComputer In arrComputers
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objProcess = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Process")


strCommand = "sc config lanmanserver start= demand"
strCommand2 = "Net start lanmanserver"

errReturn = objProcess.Create(strCommand, null, null, intProcessID)

 If errReturn = 0 Then
     Wscript.Echo "Lanmanserver was changed to manual: " & intProcessID
 Else
     Wscript.Echo "WinRM could not be started due to error: " & errReturn
 End If

wscript.sleep 5000 '5 seconds

errReturn = objProcess.Create(strCommand2, null, null, intProcessID)

 If errReturn = 0 Then
     Wscript.Echo "The Server Service was started with a process ID: " & intProcessID
 Else
     Wscript.Echo "The Server Service could not be started due to error: " & errReturn
end if
next
```